# html printing with page-break-inside:avoid

Tags: html, printing, page-break-inside

I have a lot of divs on a page with variable amounts of content in them. I have set `page-break-inside: avoid;` for these divs. Now the question is how I can reorder this divs to print efficiently.

**For example:**

```
div1 - content occupies half paper page
div2 - content occupies full paper page
div3 - content occupies half paper page
```

When printing these out - they will use 3 pages. Is it possible to reorder them like so:

```
div1
div3
div2
```

This way they will only use 2 pages of paper.

Is there a way to re-organize the `div` elements to efficiently print?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you have specific sizes, a start would be to set your width, height in px knowing that 100px = 2.645833333cm and play accordingly